# How to get value from Yii2 ActiveQuery array

Tags: php, yii2

I have a table containing fields

```
id, vehicle_id, vehicle_rating_type, vehicle_rating, rating_time
```

I want to get values based in `vehicle_id`, so I fired query

```
$id = Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id');
$data = VehicleRating::find()->where(['vehicle_id' => $id]);
```

Now when I prints `$data` array in view file using `print_r` function I get following result.

```
yii\db\ActiveQuery Object ( 
    [sql] => 
    [on] => 
    [joinWith] => 
    [select] => 
    [selectOption] => 
    [distinct] => 
    [from] => 
    [groupBy] => 
    [join] => 
    [having] => 
    [union] => 
    [params] => Array ( ) 
    [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
    [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array ( ) 
    [where] => Array ( 
        [vehicle_id] => 1 
    ) 
    [limit] => 
    [offset] => 
    [orderBy] => 
    [indexBy] => 
    [modelClass] => backend\models\VehicleRating 
    [with] => 
    [asArray] => 
    [multiple] => 
    [primaryModel] => 
    [link] => 
    [via] => 
    [inverseOf] => 
)
```

How to retrive values from this array to show in view file? Say I want to say `vehicle_id` and `vehicle_rating`. How to print it?

Answer (score 1):

You should simply execute the query, e.g. :

```
$rating = VehicleRating::find()->where(['vehicle_id' => $id])->one();
echo $rating->vehicle_rating;
```

Or if you want array instead of object :

```
$rating = VehicleRating::find()->where(['vehicle_id' => $id])->asArray()->one();
echo $rating['vehicle_rating'];
```

Read more : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#querying-data

Answer (score 0):

Use [query params](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#$params-detail).

```
$vehicleRatingQuery = VehicleRating::find()->where('vehicle_id = :vehicleId', [
    ':vehicleId' => $id
]);

$vehicleRatingQueryParams = $vehicleRatingQuery->params;
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution i added ->one() at the end of query and it works

```
$data = VehicleRating::find()->where(['vehicle_id' => $id])->one();
```